# iptables error: unknown option --dport

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

The command iptables no longer recognizes one of the most commonly used options when defining rules: `--dport`.

I get this error:

```
[root@dragonweyr /home/calyodelphi]# iptables -A INPUT --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT_TCP_UDP
iptables v1.4.7: unknown option `--dport'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

The add rule command above is just an example for enabling Terraria connections.

Here's what I currently have as a barebones iptables configuration (`listiptables` is aliased to `iptables -L -v --line-numbers`), and it's obvious that `--dport` has worked in the past:

```
root@dragonweyr /home/calyodelphi]# listiptables 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       39  4368 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
2      114 10257 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
3        1    64 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:EtherNet/IP-1 
4       72 11610 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 91 packets, 10045 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ACCEPT_TCP_UDP (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

I'm also trying to define a custom chain (inspired by [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/508700/reduce-firewall-rules-by-half-one-iptables-rule-for-tcp-and-udp)) to accept tcp & udp connections so that I don't have to define two rules for everything that I want to enable tcp and udp for (such as a Minecraft or Terraria server, or another service entirely). But even this doesn't work:

```
[root@dragonweyr /home/calyodelphi]# iptables -P ACCEPT_TCP_UDP DROP
iptables: Bad built-in chain name.
```

This is getting to be very frustrating, in polite terms (the amount of cussing involved with this would make a sailor tell me to watch my mouth). My Google-fu is terrible, so I've yet to find a working solution for any of this. I'm running CentOS 6.5 on the router. Any help and pointers that you guys can offer would be awesome.

EDIT:

Bonus question: I'm also planning to configure port forwarding as well. Is it still necessary to set rules to accept incoming connections over specific ports?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First give a `-p` option like `-p tcp` or `-p udp`.

Examples:

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT

You could also try `-p all` but I've never done that and don't find too much support for it in the examples.

Comment: I just tried this with `-p all` and I got exactly the same error. `unknown option --dport`. It worked with `-p tcp` but that's not really going to help me in this case since it just leads to the same problem: defining individual tcp/udp rules for everything.

Comment: From my experience, using `all` never worked with specifying a port. However, instead of having multiple rules for different protocols, you can think about the rules in a different direction. Create rules based on the protocol and then use the `multiports` option to group some rules together.

Comment: So, if I want to enable Terraria and Minecraft connections, I can use multiports to open 7777 and 25565, and create a TCP and UDP rule for each pair of ports?

Comment: The option to -p has to be a single protocol that has the concept of ports (`-p ICMP --dport whatever` would not work either, for obvious reasons).

Comment: in iptables v1.8.4 you need to run the command as sudo, otherwise you will receiv the above mentioned error

Comment: `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j DROP` still doesn't work; gives the error `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"`

Answer (score 35):

Another possible solution is that you're forgetting to run as root. I just ran into this when using the debian tutorial

```
$ iptables -t nat -p tcp -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"
$ sudo iptables -t nat -p tcp -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
# OK
```

Comment: Wow this is a really bad error message... Thanks!

Comment: incredible, instead of error, the output must say 'run as root' :D

Answer (score 13):

Protocol (-p) is required if you use --dport. Example:

```
-p tcp
```

Comment: Additionally, it must specify a protocol that has the concept of ports, as @FalconMomot pointed out in a comment earlier.

Comment: You are right, for that detail :)

Comment: Personally, I have the error even with `-p tcp`. `$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 62668 -j ACCEPT` returns `iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): unknown option "--dport"`
`

Answer (score 5):

If `iptables` report that it uses `nftables`, one needs to use `iptables-legacy` instead.

For Example:
Use `iptables-legacy -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j DROP`
Instead of `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j DROP`

---

It's kind of old question, but that's the first in the search results.

Comment: `iptables-legacy` is not available for much longer. So the real question is: Why does it fail with `ipatbles-nft` and how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

@dmourati and @diegows already answered your first question, so I'll tackle your second question. And bonus question. And I'll also throw in a bonus tip ;)

`iptables -P` **only** accepts BUILT-IN chains. In the `filter` table, that would be `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, and `FORWARD` chains.

Port forwarding does not get handled by the `INPUT` chain, so you don't have to open the port in the `INPUT` chain. It **does** get handled by the `FORWARD` chain, though. Be careful on that.

**Bonus tip:** When learning and/or troubleshooting `iptables`, the output of `iptables-save` is heads & shoulders better than the output of `iptables -L -v --line-numbers`. Try it, you'll be pleasantly surprised :)

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but I'm a little surprised by your last comment.  I **hate** diagnosing `iptables` issues from the `-save` output; why do you find it better than `iptables -L -n -v [--line-numbers]`?

Comment: @MadHatter simple example: You can easily see that rules with the `--dport` options actually has `-p tcp` in front. You can also see how/when rule processing jumps from a built-in chain (e.g., INPUT) to a custom chain (e.g., ACCEPT_TCP_UDP). These two important information are _not_ visible in the output of `iptables -L -n`.

Comment: Another benefit: I can do `iptables-save > somefile`, edit `somefile` using vim, then doing `iptables-apply -t 600 somefile` to test it. If I inadvertently block myself out, after 600 seconds the rules revert.

Comment: The bonus tip is very much appreciated, and already being used. I'd been using `iptables-save` to help myself learn from a raw config dump before I asked this question. I did not expect the `FORWARD` chain to be where I need to pay attention for port forwarding, however. I'll have to read up about that.

Comment: @CalyoDelphi if you do a search for "netfilter packet flow diagram", you'll see where every table & chain applies ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an edge case scenario, but I got this error when I had apparently upgraded my kernel and not rebooted yet and some kernel module was not loaded yet. The module could not be loaded because the running kernel was a different version than the installed kernel. Rebooting solved the problem.