# iptables not accepting my rule

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, routing, nftables

I am trying to add a rule to my iptables, so that traffic trying to connect on port 9091 is forwarded to a different IP address. When searching I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network) answer, which seems to fit my exact use case. When adopting the rule shown with my IP addresses and ports it looks like:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.54 -p tcp --dport 9091 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.53`

But when running I get the error:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.54 -p tcp --dport 9091 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.53
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I am not sure what's going on, everywhere I look, it says you have to make sure to specify a protocol before using the `--dport` option, but I am clearly specifying tcp. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iptables error: unknown option --dport](https://serverfault.com/questions/563033/iptables-error-unknown-option-dport)

Comment: No. I posted my own answer. I was getting this error, but in reality, it was just because I wasn't running the command as root. I figured it would have given me a permission error instead, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: `I posted my own answer` which is the second answer in the link provided ..

Answer (score -1):

Okay well after an annoying hour this had a silly fix. I simply just wasn't running the command with `sudo`.

I don't work with `iptables` a bunch, so I wanted to get the syntax correct first, and then I assumed it would tell me it wasn't working because I didn't have permission. For some reason it just spits out the `unknown option "--dport"` instead though, but as soon as I ran it with `sudo` it worked.

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.54 -p tcp --dport 9091 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.53`